# Change Date and Time of Creation and Modification of file based on filename in MacOS folder

Tags: bash, macos, date, time, touch

I have a lot of files in folder with filenames like

```
20190618_213557.mp4
20190620_231105.mp4
20190623_101654.mp4
..
```

I need to change creation date and time based on filename 
20190618_213557=YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS
using bash script in terminal

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/79460/how-to-change-inode-change-time-of-a-file

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, an upvote/accept would be highly appreciated. If not, I would be happy to hear what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
MACOS Uses touch -mt to change file creation/modification time. Here is the script:

    #!/bin/bash
    FILES="/Users/shakirzareen/Desktop/untitledfolder/*"
    for f in $FILES         ## f = full path + filename
    do
        t="${f##*/}"            ##remove folder path from filename
        t2="${t//_}"            ##remove _ from filename
        t3="${t2%%.*}"          ##remove file extension part
        touch -mt "$t3" $f  ##set creation and modification time of file
    done
```

Comment: You can use following method to change date:

t3="20120101"
t3=$(date -j -f %Y%m%d -v-1400d $t3 +%Y%m%d)
echo $t3

Comment: I mean: how to change kMDItemDateAdded and kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking

Comment: I am afraid not. Many posts on internet about this topic but no one gives a method to update kMDItemDateAdded.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176006/set-file-metadata-attribute-values
P.S: Dont forget to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

To bystanders reading this: Please note that this question and answer are for Mac OS. In Linux there is no file creation time in most cases.

---

The `touch` command can change the creation date of your files. From `man touch`

> `-t STAMP` use `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]` instead of current time

So we only have to convert your format `YYYYMMDD_hhmmss` into `touch`'s format. This can be done with `bash`'s parameter substitution. We exttract the substrings `YYYYMMDD` (`${x:0:8}`), `hhmm` (`${x:9:4}`), and `ss` (`${x:13:2}`) and put them together.

```
for i in *.mp4; do
    touch -t "${x:0:8}${x:9:4}.${x:13:2}" "$i"
done
```

More options for `touch` that might be of interest to you:

> `-c` Do not create the file if it does not exist.
>   `-a` Change [only] the access time of the file.
>   `-m` Change [only] the modification time of the file.

However, [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99599) claimed that this would only change the creation date if the specified date was before the current creation date. If that's the case and you want to change the time to something after the original creation date use ...

```
for i in *.mp4; do
   SetFile -d "${x:4:2}/${x:6:2}/${x:0:4} ${x:9:2}:${x:11:2}:${x:13:2}" "$i"
done
```

`SetFile` may have to be installed first.

Comment: Your command does not change the "creation time" of the file. A file does not have a "creation time", only "access time", "modification time" and the time of last "inode change", and even the latter can not be modified.

Comment: @user1934428 While your claim may be true on Linux, OP tagged their question as [tag:macos]. On Mac OS files have a creation date (called *birth*) and `touch` (sometimes) changes this date -- see the answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99536).

Comment: I thought the idea of not having a creation time is common to all Unix flavours (where this concept emerged), and since MacOS has BSD in its core, I blindly assumed it would be there the same. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems trying to set the date from filename, and struggled a lot with the code suggested here.

Have to be careful to use the same variable letter for the loop and in the brackets! `for i in... {x:4:2}` should be `for i in... {i:4:2}` at least on mac and finish with a semicolon before done. This code should work:

```
for i in *.mp4; do
   SetFile -d "${i:4:2}/${i:6:2}/${i:0:4} ${i:9:2}:${i:11:2}:${i:13:2}" "$i";
done
```